# Implement operation and simulation mode in an interface

Tags: python, simulation

**Context:**

I have to create an interface between devices and a client.
My package is composed of:

- Device.py
- Error.py
- DeviceA.py (for example)
- DeviceB.py
- ...

Basically each `DeviceA`, `DeviceB`, ... inherit Device class. `Device` is composed of one FSM (state machine: module Fysom) and does several thing about communication, parsing, ... The purpose is to have one common FSM (same rules) for all devices but each device follow his own FSM. That's why there is one thread per device (Device inherit a Threading module).
A code simplified:

```
# One common state rule
TableFSM = {
'initial' : 'none',
'events': [
    {'name': 'do_start', 'src': ['OFF', 'none'], 'dst': 'LOADED'},
    {'name': 'do_stop', 'src': ['LOADED'], 'dst': 'OFF'},
    # same for resume, pause, ...
]

class Device(MyThread):
    def __init__(self):
        # FSM is instantiate here so ONE FSM per device with same rule
        self.fsm = Fysom(TableFSM)
        self.mode = "operation" #or simulation
    def start(self):
        self.fsm.do_start()
        # Real common Device parsing stuff
    def stop(self):
        self.fsm.do_stop()
        # Real common Device parsing stuff
    def pause(self):
        self.fsm.do_pause()
        # Real common Device parsing stuff
    def resume(self):
        self.fsm.do_resume()
        # Real common Device parsing stuff


class DeviceA(Device):
    def __init__(self):
        Device.__init__(self)
    def start(self):
        #Specific Real Device stuff
        super(DeviceA, self).start()
    def stop(self):            
        #Specific Real Device stuff
        super(DeviceA, self).start()
    #def ...

class DeviceB(Device):
    def __init__(self):
        Device.__init__(self)
    def start(self):
        #Specific Real Device stuff
        super(DeviceB, self).start()
    def stop(self):            
        #Specific Real Device stuff
        super(DeviceB, self).start()
    #def ...
```

Here methods called will be `DeviceA().start()` or `DeviceB().stop()` (bad represention) for example.

**Issue:**

I have to implement for each device an *operation* and *simulation* mode
For example  I could add in each method of each device class the following statement:

```
if self.mode == "operation":
    #some stuff
elif self.mode == "simulated":
    #almost nothing
```

I want to write it as generic as possible.
From [a previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23762104/simulation-operation-mode-in-class) I could derivate `SimuDevice` from `Device` with the same methods. Basically `SimuDevice` will only trigger the FSM :

```
class DeviceSimu(Device):
    def __init__(self):
        Device.__init__(self)
    def start(self):
        self.fsm.do_start()
    def stop(self):
        self.fsm.do_stop()
    def pause(self):
        self.fsm.do_pause()
    def resume(self):
        self.fsm.do_resume()
```

**Question:**

My issue is about instanciation and object. I want to be able to switch between *operation* and *simulation* mode without deleting and reinstantiate an object.

1. I can't understand how `DeviceA` could access to `DeviceSimu` method?
2. Is it a good way (conceptually) to do simulation and operation mode? Maybe I have to change the link between class.
3. Any other advice ?

Comment: You mention "each device follow his own FSM", but the code you posted does not include that. Could you expand the code to better illustrate what goes on in there?

Comment: @JanneKarila: I am actually using Fysom module and inheriting a `MyThread` class. Updated post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You **could** simply have if-statements in each method of your class. This would probably result in (slightly) lesser lines of code than my suggestions. However, I think that solution has a lot of repeated code and is quite static. What if you wanted a device that simply simulates? Or one that simply operates?

My suggestion is to abstract the classes a bit more and have seperate classes for each mode. Then have a final `DualModeDevice` class that inherits from both of them:

```
class OperationDevice(Device):
    def __init__(self):
        super(OperationDevice, self).__init__()

    def operation_start(self):
        # Do operation specific code
        self.start()

    def operation_stop(self):
        # Do operation specific code
        self.stop()

    def operation_pause(self):
        # Do operation specific code
        self.pause()

    def operation_resume(self):
        # Do operation specific code
        self.resume()


class SimulationDevice(Device):
    def __init__(self):
        super(SimulationDevice, self).__init__()

    def simulation_start(self):
        # Do simulation specific code
        self.start()

    def simulation_stop(self):
        # Do simulation specific code
        self.stop()

    def simulation_pause(self):
        # Do simulation specific code
        self.pause()

    def simulation_resume(self):
        # Do simulation specific code
        self.resume()


class DualModeDevice(OperationDevice, SimulationDevice):
    def __init__(self, mode='simulation'):
        super(DualModeDevice, self).__init__()
        self._mode = mode

        # To be continued
```

Each function in `SimulationDevice` and `OperationDevice` needs to be named differently because of how [Python interprets and resolves inheritence](https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.2.3/descrintro/#cooperation). If there is a identically named function from multiple inheritances, it will use the first available reference from the MRO (method resolution order).

Now with that being said, you could implement dual mode in two ways:

1. Function mapping

   One way is to simply have a `dict` that holds a mapping from `mode` to `function`:

   ```
   class DualModeDevice(OperationDevice, SimulationDevice):
       def __init__(self, mode='simulation'):
           super(DualModeDevice, self).__init__()
           self._mode = mode
           self._start_map = {
               'simulation': self.simulation_start,
               'operation': self.operation_start
           }
           # Repeat the above line for `stop`, `pause`, and `resume`.
           # Or you could combine them into a single `dict`.

       def stop(self):
           self._start_map[self._mode]()

       def stop(self):
           self._stop_map[self._mode]()
   ```
2. `getattr`

   If you felt like being sneaky, you could use the `getattr` function (assuming consistent function names):

   ```
   class DualModeDevice(OperationDevice, SimulationDevice):
       def __init__(self, mode='simulation'):
           self._mode = mode

       def run_command(self, command, mode=self.mode):
           getattr(self, '{}_{}'.format(mode, command))()
   ```

   Since functions boil down to callable properties in classes, we can simply use `getattr` to get the correct function, then call it.

Comment: Ty for help. Solution 1 is pretty nice. I think now I can remove `Device` class (abstract class with almost nothing) and inheritate to `MyThread` instead. **Question:** Now `DeviceA`, `DeviceB`, ... should derivate from `DualModeDevice` I guess. So I need to had `self.operation_start = OperationDevice.__init__(self)` and `self.simulation_start = SimulationDevice.__init__(self)` in init of `DualModeDevice`?

Comment: No. What you would be doing with those lines is storing the return value of the `__init__` functions to a variable. `__init__` in this solution doesn't return anything (i.e. will 'return' `None`). When structuring your classes, start with the basics: what do ALL devices do? Put those funtions into your base class. Then specialize: what do simulation devices need to do? Operation devices? Those are new classes that inherit from your base. Then: do you need a single device to do both? Have another class that inherits from the simulation and operation devices.

Comment: Ok ty, actually all device need both Operation and Simulation and are able to switch so `DualModeDevice` answer the problem. But I don't see what `self.simulation_start` and `self.operation_start` is refering. To my mind it should be respectively object of `SimulationDevice` and `OperationDevice` ? How could I specify it?

Comment: Gotcha, I see. `self.simulation_start` and `self.operation_start` are function references from the classes `DualModeOperation` inherits from. By inheriting from `SimuationDevice` and `OperationDevice`, `DualModeDevice` has access to their methods; all we need to do is reference them at the right times.

Comment: Well ok sorry now I really see what you mean. better with `super(DualModeDevice, self).__init__()`

Comment: I would be careful with changing `self.simulation_start` to `SimuationDevice.simulation_start`. [This could error](http://codepad.org/T5k39bB5) depending on your implementation of `simulation_start`. I think you are getting confused with my `super().__init__` syntax. All that does is call the constructors of its parent class(es). So once that line completes, `DualModeDevice` **is** a `SimulationDevice` and an `OperationDevice`. Thus using `self.simulation_start` is calling the [**exactly** like](http://codepad.org/gdLl3SrR) calling that method on an instance of `SimulationDevice`.

Comment: Yes I know but I can't combine `super` with old style and old style is already in use.

Answer (score 0):

How about this: split `DeviceA` into two classes. `DeviceA` could manage the state machine and `DeviceAConnection` could handle the communication with the physical device. Then create a `DeviceASimulation` class that implements the same interface as `DeviceAConnection` but simulates the device. Now `DeviceA` would be able to switch between the real and simulated connections without restarting the state machine.

Comment: `DeviceA`, `DeviceB`, ... (at least 8 device classes). It could be pretty  long code. The purpose is to have something almost well designed and avoid repetition.