# Call method of specific parent class

Tags: python, inheritance

This question is related to this [topic](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/51298/implement-operation-and-simulation-mode-in-an-interface).

Context:

```
class OperationDevice(Device):
    def __init__(self):
        super(OperationDevice, self).__init__()

    def operation_start(self):
        # Do operation specific code
        self.start()

    def operation_stop(self):
        # Do operation specific code
        self.stop()


class SimulationDevice(Device):
    def __init__(self):
        super(SimulationDevice, self).__init__()

    def simulation_start(self):
        # Do simulation specific code
        self.fsm.start()

    def simulation_stop(self):
        # Do simulation specific code
        self.fsm.stop()


class DualModeDevice(OperationDevice, SimulationDevice):
    def __init__(self, mode='simulation'):
        super(DualModeDevice, self).__init__()
        self._mode = mode
        self._start_map = {
            'simulation': self.simulation_start,
            'operation': self.operation_start
        }
        self._stop_map = {
            'simulation': self.simulation_stop,
            'operation': self.operation_stop
        }

    def start(self):
        self._start_map[self._mode]()

    def stop(self):
        self._stop_map[self._mode]()
```

Here I have to define in `OperationDevice` and `SimulationDevice` different method name like `simulation_start` and `operation_start` (because of MRO).

- I actually want to define the same method name for both class and be able to call each one from `DualModeDevice` or subclasses.
  For example `operation_start` from `OperationDevice` and `simulation_start` from `SimulationDevice` will become `start`. Is it possible and how?
- This solution is a way to switch between class `OperationDevice` and `SimulationDevice` following value of mode. I am wondering wether is it possible to define automatically all method from `SimulationDevice` linked with `mode = "simulation"` (same for `OperationDevice` with `"operation"`) without having to specify for each method (`self._start_map` for example) in constructor (init) of `DualModeDevice`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use composition instead of inheritance:

```
class OperationDevice(Device):
    def __init__(self):
        super(OperationDevice, self).__init__()

    def start(self):
        # Do operation specific code

    def stop(self):
        # Do operation specific code


class SimulationDevice(Device):
    def __init__(self):
        super(SimulationDevice, self).__init__()

    def start(self):
        # Do simulation specific code
        self.fsm.start()

    def stop(self):
        # Do simulation specific code
        self.fsm.stop()


class DualModeDevice(Device):
    def __init__(self, mode='simulation'):
        super(DualModeDevice, self).__init__()
        self._mode = mode
        self._mode_map = {
            'simulation': SimulationDevice(),
            'operation': OperationDevice()
        }

    def start(self):
        self._mode_map[self._mode].start()

    def stop(self):
        self._mode_map[self._mode].stop()
```

Comment: Ty you almost answered my question (+1). I want also to remove start and stop in `DualModeDevice` by using `__getattribute__(self, name): getattr(self._mode_map[self._mode], name)`. But it calls method from Device class. Is it possible to update answer with `__getattr__` method instead of start and stop? Ty again

Comment: @Katsu Such magic can make code hard to follow. I'd rather live with some boilerplate code.

Comment: @JanneKarila well ok I created a dedicated [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24010922/getattr-and-composition-inheritance) for this). Now do you think is it necessary to keep inheritance between `DualModeDevice` and `Device` since there is composition?

Comment: @Katsu No, unless there is something else that the classes could share via inheritance.

Answer (score 2):

> I am wondering wether is it possible to define automatically all method from SimulationDevice linked with mode = "simulation" (same for OperationDevice with "operation") without having to specify for each method (self._start_map for example) in constructor (init) of DualModeDevice.

You could do this using `__getattribute__`. Something like:

```
def __getattribute__(self, name):
    if name in methods_to_map:
        return getattr(self.handler, name)
    return super(...).__getattribute__(name)
```

You would list the method names that you want to map based on mode in `methods_to_map` (as strings). Then you would set `handler` to the *class* implementing the current mode. E.g. `self.mode = 'simulation' -> self.handler = SimulationDevice`.

Comment: Ty for help. Is it possible to get more details about setting `handler` to the class because here `DualDeviceMode` derivate both class?

Answer (score 2):

You could map the individual parent to a specific mode in you maps as such:

```
class DualModeDevice(OperationDevice, SimulationDevice):
    def __init__(self, mode='simulation'):
        super(DualModeDevice, self).__init__()
        self._mode = mode
        self._mode_map = {
            'simulation': SimulationDevice,
            'operation': OperationDevice
        }
```

Then in your `DualModeDevice` methods do call those functions, passing in `self`:

```
def start(self):
    self._mode_map[self._mode].start(self)
```

Comment: Ty same comment as above (+1).